# how to set default font family available in android to action bar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, truetype, android-fonts

- I just set the font family `sans-serif-medium-condensed` in `AppTheme` in `styles`.
- I know how to set font family to all text views buttons etc. except `Action bar title`
- Is there any way I can change the `Action bar title` font family to `sans-serif-medium`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a **`Toolbar`** you can use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
          app:titleTextAppearance="@style/myTitleTextAppearance"
```

with:

```
    <style name="myTitleTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
        <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
         .....
    </style>
```

with an **`ActionBar`** you add in your app theme the `actionBarStyle` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="myActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.PrimarySurface">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/myActionBarTextTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="myActionBarTextTitle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it's working, but why both android:fontFamily and fontFamily is set ?

Comment: @naanu If you don't need to support devices < 16 and aren't using AppCompat, you should set `android:fontFamily` instead of `fontFamily` or `app:fontFamily`. In case you can check the styles in Material Components. They are both set in all TextAppearance styles.